# If I make holes to a pipe and make water flow through it, will water come out from all holes at the same flow rate once the whole pipe is filled?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am wondering because I want to set this up at a small scale (with a 5 V pump, 0.7 W, 120 L/h or what's the same... 0.33 L each 10 seconds) and an 8 mm diameter 1 m long flexible tube **with a closed end**.

And before buying things, I want to gain some insight.

My intuition says that once the tube is filled, the pressure that is "generated" by the pump, will make the water push against the pipe "walls" with the same force, everywhere. So... as long as all holes are the same, or very similar, water should flow out at the same rate from all holes.

I lack the deeper understanding of the laws that great people have found out along the recent centuries, that's why I ask here :-)

Comment: Clearly there is a hole size where nearly all the water comes out the first hole. But there is also a limit where the pumping capacity fair outstrips the ability of all the holes to release that much water.

Answer (score 4):

Good first thought, but some things can make a difference. Fluid dynamics can be complicated.

When water is still the situation is simpler. Pressure is higher at the bottom of a container. So if you hang a hose vertically, water will flow out of holes near the bottom faster than the top.

If water is flowing, pressure isn't the same everywhere. Suppose your hose made a sharp turn. Water would have to stop flowing forward and start flowing sideways. It takes a force to make water turn. The pressure would be higher there. The force comes from the walls of the hose pushing on the water. They push as hard as necessary to keep the water inside. You can see the same thing by pushing on a wall of your house. You can push hard or gently. Either way, the wall pushes back just hard enough to keep you from moving forward.

Friction matters. If you have a long hose, water will slow down as it goes. It will flow out the near holes faster than the far holes. The diameter of the pipe matters. In a narrow pipe, all the water is close to the walls so all the water is more affected by friction. Water speed matters too.

The size of the holes matters. More water will flow out of a big hole.

It is very hard to get an intuitive feel for how fluids behave. They often do surprising things.

Comment: Thanks. What I get from this, is that I have to try and see. The good thing is, the scenario will stay constant (one pump, one tube, one position). So, I can play with making near holes smaller and the others bigger, to compensate for friction.